# Unsupported Media type while calling DELETE from JMeter with no body

Tags: jmeter

I have created a resource using JMeter script and now want to delete it using JMeter only.
My DELETE API has no body. Its format is DELETE resource/id

However, my DELETE HTTP request is failing with below error

```
{
  "code" : "UnsupportedMediaType",
  "message" : "Unsupported Media Type"
}
```

I see that in DELETE request headers, I have :

```
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/1.8.0_271)
```

Since its DELETE, I don't expect Content-Type etc but its calculated on its own. Kindly suggest.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per [HTTP 415 status code description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415):

> The HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type client error response code indicates that the server refuses to accept the request because the payload format is in an unsupported format.
>
> The format problem might be due to the request's indicated [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) or [Content-Encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding), or as a result of inspecting the data directly.

So my expectation is that you need to add a [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-header-manager) and configure it to send the aforementioned `Content-Type` header with the value of [`application/json`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Metadata_and_schema)

[image]